# Mongoose findOne cannot access sub-collection of the collection

Tags: node.js, mongoose, graphql, mongoose-schema

Hello I have a problem with my requests

when I do a user.findOne ({_id: id})
the results do not give me all I want that is to say the subobjects only come with their _id and the other data are null
like if I want to access item.structure._id it passes but if I access item.structure.address it gives me null

this is my schema

```
        interface ISubscription extends Document {
       _id: Types.ObjectId;
        subscription: Types.ObjectId;
         date_start: string;
        date_end: string;
      
     }
    export interface IUser extends Document {
             structure?: IStructure;
             assurance?: Types.ObjectId;
             firstname?: string;
             lastname?: string;
             phoneNumber?: string;
             username?: string;
             email?: string;
             password?: string;
             address?: string;
             description?: string;
             status?: STATUS_USER;
           state?: STATE;
  
  
    }
```

and when a excute my request I have a response like that

```
    {
  status: 'ACTIVATE',
  state: 'NOTPAYE',
  _id: 613a103c5f300f1a61daa997,
  password: '$2b$10$NDmCx.pk5GHtUGIyQY0Cx.jGLkRJInbKSuu2B/d1XdRmo8dULXNSW',
  phoneNumber: '772503530',
  firstname: 'Khazim',
  lastname: 'NDIAYE',
  email: 'zimkha@jaba.store',
  username: 'zimtheSniper',
  address: 'Parcelle Assainies',
  nationality: 'Sénégalais',
  indicatif: '+221',
  country: 'Sénégal',
  subscriptions: [],
  createdAt: 2021-09-09T13:46:36.731Z,
  updatedAt: 2021-09-09T17:04:48.083Z,
  __v: 0,
  isDeleted: false,
  phone_home_working: '771458633',
  structure: {
    _id: 613a2bd6fb22783a03737537,
    name: 'true',
    createdAt: 2021-09-09T17:04:48.083Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-09-09T17:04:48.083Z
  }
}
```

you see the sub-collection structure I can access only on the identifier and not on the other attributes ca its sending me null

Someone can help me for this

Comment: I can only see 4 properties inside the **strcuture** and it does not include the **address** property. Are you sure you have the address stored in the structure object? Please verify it from the DB, and if it's there then kindly share the query that you are running to fetch this document.

Comment: the problem is that apart from the identifier I cannot access any of the other properties of the sub-collection

Comment: Can you please share the definition (resolver) of this mutataion?

Comment: @ammer now you can see my type deifinition  and resolver

Comment: In your DB, is **structure** a separate document/table? If yes, then you need to populate it in the resolver query. Otherwise do `console.log(users)` after this line `const users = await User.find();`

Comment: structure is a document in my database and when I do console.log(users) , 
look at my last comment you will see the result of a console.log

Answer (score 0):

I show you a request where I save data thanks to the Apollo playground

```
 JS
 mutation{
  updateStructure(id: "613a2bd6fb22783a03737537",  input:{
    address: "Cambérene2"
    phoneNumber: "338545625"
    description: "Une clinique"
    email: "clinic@email.com"
    isDeleted: false
  })
  {
     code
    error
    message
    data{
      _id
      address
      phoneNumber
      description
      email
    }
  }
}
```

this is my response : Success

```
 JSON
 {
  "data": {
    "updateStructure": {
      "code": 200,
      "error": "Success",
      "message": "Succès",
      "data": {
        "_id": "613a2bd6fb22783a03737537",
        "address": "Cambérene2",
        "phoneNumber": "338545625",
        "description": "Une clinique",
        "email": "clinic@email.com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my Query for get All user

```
  getUsers: async (_: any, args: any): Promise<any> => {
    try {
      return await userServices.getAllUsers();
    } catch (e) {
      return fnReturn({
        error: e.stack,
        message: e.message,
        data: null as any,
        code: httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
      })
    }
  }
```

the getAllUser function un my services

```
static getAllUsers = async (): Promise<IReturn> => {
    try {
      const users = await User.find();
      if (users.length == 0) {
        return fnReturn({
          error: null as any,
          code: httpStatus.OK,
          message: 'Aucune donnée trouvé',
          data: null as any
        })
      }
      return fnReturn({
        error: null as any,
        code: httpStatus.OK,
        message: 'Les users',
        data: users
      })
    } catch (error) {
      return fnReturn({
        error: error.stack,
        code: httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        message: error.message,
        data: null as any
      })
    }
  }
```

My type definition

```
 type Structure {
  _id: ID
 address: String
 phoneNumber: String
 description: String
 email: String
 photo: String
 isDeleted: Boolean
 createdAt: String
 updatedAt: String
}
 
 type User {
    _id: ID!
    password: String
    phoneNumber:  String
    firstname: String
    lastname: String
    email:  String
    username: String
    address:  String
    status: StatusUser
    state: String
    tokenForSetting: Token
    role: Role
    specialite: String
    structure: Structure
    nationality: String
    indicatif: String
    country: String
    description: String
    homeworking: String
    email_home_working:String
    phone_home_working: String
    photo: String
    isDeleted:Boolean
    assurance_tpc: number
  }
  enum StatusUser{
    ACTIVATE
    DISABLED
}
enum State {
  PAYE
  NOTPAYE
}
enum Role{
    CANCELLED
    CONFIRMED
    REFUSED
    PENDING
}
type UserCreationResponse{
    code: Int
    error: String
    message: String
    data: User
}
type UserListResponse{
    code: Int
    error: String
    message: String
    data: [User]
}
type UserDeletedResponse{
    code: Int
    error: String
    message: String
    data: Boolean
}
   type Token {
      id: ID
      token: String!
  }
  input inputToken {
    token: String
  }

input UserInput {
    password: String!
    phoneNumber:  String!
    firstname: String
    lastname: String
    email:  String
    username: String
    address:  String
    status: StatusUser
    state: State
    tokenForSetting: inputToken
    role: Role
    specialite: String
    Structure: String
    nationality: String
    indicatif: String
    country: String
    description: String
    homeworking: String
    email_home_working:String
    phone_home_working: String
    photo: String
    isDeleted:Boolean
    assurance_tpc: number
}

 type AuthPayload {
    userId: ID!
    token: String!
    tokenExpiration: Int!
  }
```